# Adding 2D plane to 3D view

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 3D scene and I would like to add a 2D plane to the scene where I could add buttons. I could do this with 3D plane, but I can't figure out how to make camera ignore the perspective of it. Any suggestions how can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: It might be best to use sprites for this. I would actually just use the DOM to create a 2d element on top of your 3d element, its much easier to trigger events on that and make that influence your 3d view.

Comment: somethinghere right about you should use DOM, but you will need this extensions to move the DOM element to correct position in 3D: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.objcoord

Comment: @somethinghere thanks for the advice! I want to make a transparent menu overlay, so I don't have to worry about flickering etc, I can simply specify a higher z-index and that's it, correct?

Comment: I think thats how it works, yes, just define stuff in the DOM itself (outside your canvas) and position both absolute and you should have an overlay. @BenMack I don't think you even need to worry about three.js here, just build your stuff like you would build a regular website and use the canvas as the, well, canvas. You can easily influence things in the canvas with the DOM as its all just JS.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you will post an 'answer' I will accept it, thanks!

Comment: if you will use the plane as a menu, you could use [dat.gui](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/14/dat-gui-simple-ui-for-demos/). See [this example](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it quickly just use an absolute positioned div.
If you need more advanced GUI features, like marcel wrote, just use dat.gui. It is fairly responsive and many Three.js examples are using it (controls often on the upper right side of the screen).